# Template, Inheritance, static member incrementation

Tags: c++

the following code in my opinion should output sum sizeof(int) + sizeof(float) + sizeof(std::string), but the storage value is always zero. Why?

```cpp
struct Base {
    static int IncrementID(int x) {
        static int id = 0;
        storage += x;
        return id++;
    }
    static int storage;
};
int Base::storage = 0;

template<typename T>
struct Object : public Base {
    static const int id;
};
template<typename T>
const int Object<T>::id(Base::IncrementID(sizeof(T)));

int main() {
    Object<int> a;
    Object<float> b;
    Object<std::string> c;

    std::cout << Base::storage;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't use those static `id` data members in any way that can cause their implicit instantiation. It means they don't have to be instantiated (nor their initialization has to happen). To quote the C++ standard:

> **[temp.inst]**
>
> [3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.inst#3) Unless a member of a class template or a member template has
>   been explicitly instantiated or explicitly specialized, the
>   specialization of the member is implicitly instantiated when the
>   specialization is referenced in a context that requires the member
>   definition to exist; in particular, the initialization (and any
>   associated side effects) of a static data member does not occur unless
>   the static data member is itself used in a way that requires the
>   definition of the static data member to exist.

Doing something as simple as adding a user defined constructor like

```
Object() {
    int i = id;
    (void)i;
}
```

[Can be enough](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/03ee0fdcfceb0181) to odr-use them, and as such force their instantiation by creating objects as you do.

Comment: BTW, if C++17 is available `static inline` does the job too.

Comment: @DeiDei - Doesn't seem to do it when I experiment with its http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/101b9717c7db71b4

Comment: Oh, I only tested with MSVC 15.9.13. Guess that's something.